# how can I select only all done Task in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

I am doing a simple task in MYSQL . As Example , There is Jib(jobId) and subjid(subJobId) and UL. SubJobId is a Id refereed to JOBID and each SubJID has a ul field , I Only need those  JID(JobId) whose UL is 1, if there is even 1 UL is 0. then it'll ignore.

please check the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcUz3.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, it's very difficult to tell what you need from the text of your question.  Usually, it's helpful to present both a few rows of sample table content and the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with a sub query.  These two will to the trick.

```
select *
  from your_schema.your_table a
  left join (select *              
               from your_schema.your_table
              where ul = 0) b
    on b.jid = a.jid
 where b.jid is null;
```

**OR**

```
select *  
  from your_schema.your_table
 where jid not in (select jid 
                     from your_schema.your_table
                    where ul = 0);
```

Comment: can you clarify me what you meaning here about your_schema?

Comment: Same as database in mysql...Basically a collection of tables.  You can ignore it if your database is already selected prior to running the query.  Just replace "your_table" with the name of your table and also exclude "your_schema".

Comment: can you just clarify me 'IN' or 'NOT IN' in mysql Query how works?
- is it query like it RUNS query with the current result of query ?

Comment: Sure, IN expects the result of the selected column in the sub query to be the same as the value in the column of the main query.  NOT IN is the opposite, main query only returns those records for which the value of the column in the NOT IN clause is not equal to the result of the column in the sub query.  So in this case the main query returns those records where jid value is not present in the result set of jid of the sub query.